jquery ajax code works on Ubuntu 20, but not on Debian. How can I make it work on Debian?
The below code works on Ubuntu 20.04 but not on Debian 12. On Ubuntu 20.04, it formats the numbers passed but on the Debian 12 setup, it places '.$cards[$i].' '; } ?> in that spot. I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?
function formatCards(cards, con) {
    cards.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
    con = con + "cards";
    // This formats the player's cards    
        $.ajax({  
          type: "GET",
          url: "format_player_cards.php?id=" + cards,
          success: function(res) {
              document.getElementById( con ).innerHTML = res;
          },
          error: function(request,status,errorThrown){console.log(request,status,errorThrown)}
        });
}

<?php
$q = $_GET["id"];
$cards = array();

$cards = explode(',', $q);
//echo count($cards);
for($i=0;$i<count($cards);$i++) {
    echo '<span style="border: 1px solid #00F;">'.$cards[$i].'</span><span> </span>';
}
?>


Make sure webserver is installed in Debian.
